# How to create a hexagonal board consisting of hexagonal cells?

Tags: javascript, jquery, 2d-games, hexagonal-tiles, hex-editors

There is a game called hexxagon that I want to develop using html/css/js . It is a board game and the board looks like the board in the picture below. I have been trying for weeks but I couldn't manage to do. Now I only want create the board and the pieces then I can focus on the algorithm later. 
please , any help would be appreciated. 
Thank you.[Photo of the board](https://i.stack.imgur.com/anBdo.jpg)

Comment: My advice it to start with javascript game basics!

Answer (score 3):

Go to [this link](https://www.redblobgames.com/grids/hexagons/). I cannot recommend his article enough: it tells you all you need to know. For displaying it, I would recommend [ROT.js](http://ondras.github.io/rot.js/manual/#intro). The page demonstrating hexagon usage is [here](http://ondras.github.io/rot.js/manual/#hex/about).

Comment: This is incredible. I can’t thank you enough for this resource, and am always on the lookout for others.